# Emoticons in a push-notification alert

Tags: iphone, push-notification, emoticons

How do I put emoticons into a push-notification alert? An example would be Ping!

Answer (score 4):

They are likely using the Emoji Japanese characters.

Comment: Didn't Apple remove support for these?

Comment: US phones can't enable the Emoji keyboard without a little trickery, but the phone is capable of displaying the characters regardless.

Comment: Are you saying then that putting it in the push wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Yep, for instance, when someone sends you a text message with Emoji in it, even if you have not enabled the Emoji keyboard on your phone, they will still appear.

Comment: Mumble mumble private-use range mumble mumble :)